# How to convert integer to string and put into array in C

Tags: arrays, c

I have an integer pointer array that I want to convert into a char array of strings. I've read of the itoa function only to find out it isn't supported on gcc.

```
char *b1; //Char pointer array
int *p; //Integer pointer array
/*
*(p+0) = 34
*(p+1) = 213
*(p+2) = 1094
*(p+3) = 9
*(p+4) = 67
*(p+5) = 576
These are values in the array
*/
```

My goal is to put these numbers into a char array so that I can use string concatenation to use in another function call. I can't simply just say `char *b[i] = *(p+i);` and I've read about sprintf and snprintf, but I don't want to print anything at all. I just want to fill an element in the char array like this: `b[1] = 213`. The values of the p array have already been set, I've just shown the method of retrieving them. How would I accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `sprintf()`.

Comment: `sprintf()` and `snprintf()` don't print anything out to an output device.

Comment: `printf()` prints the output, `sprintf()` puts the output in a string instead of printing it.

Comment: "I have an integer pointer array" and "a char array of strings" please show that as the input into an [mre] and the output target of same, instead of only a pointer to ints.

Comment: BTW, prefer `p[0]` instead of `*(p+0)`

Comment: A "string" (as mentioned by Barmar) is a sequence of characters, which can nicely be stored in an array of chars. It will be zero-terminated but that should not be a problem for whatever you want to do with it (should actually help) or could be fixed easily. So please explain, ideally referencing the documentation of sprintf/snprintf,  what keeps you from using them.

Comment: `char *b[i] = *(p+i);` depends on endienness of the system. I assume it will have different out come on different system.

Comment: Notice that `char *b1;` can't be used as an array of strings. You need `char * b1[NUMBER_OF_STRINGS]` or `char ** b1`

Comment: `asprintf()` will allocate memory for the string, but you need to remember to `free()` it when it's no longer used / accessible.